# Play timeline in reverse when holding a button

Tags: actionscript-3

Basically i'm trying to create two buttons. They both call actions while the user has their cursor held on them (rather than onClick or anything like that).

The first one plays the timeline, which works great.

The second one I need it to play the timeline in reverse while the user is holding down the button, how do I do that? Code below:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 


// Play timeline forwards on click //
function onButtonClick( event:MouseEvent ):void 
    { 
        play();
    }
RotateRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onButtonClick);

// Stop timeline forwards on release //
function onButtonClick2( event:MouseEvent ):void 
    { 
        stop();
    } 
RotateRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onButtonClick2);



// Play timeline in reverse on click //
function onButtonClick3( event:MouseEvent ):void 
    { 
        // PLAY IN REVERSE?
    }


RotateLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onButtonClick3);

// Stop timeline in reverse on release //
function onButtonClick4( event:MouseEvent ):void 
    { 
        stop();
    } 
RotateLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onButtonClick4);
```

Any help is most appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an `ENTER_FRAME` event on MOUSE_DOWN:

```
RotateLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onButtonClick3);

function onButtonClick3( event:MouseEvent ):void 
{ 
    stop();
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, reverse);
}

function reverse(e:Event):void {
    //currently, this is reversing the main timeline. Can also do it to a specific movieclip with something like myMovieClip.gotoAndStop(myMovieClip.currentFrame-1) instead. 
    gotoAndStop(currentFrame - 1);
}


RotateLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onButtonClick4);

// Stop timeline in reverse on release //
function onButtonClick4( event:MouseEvent ):void 
    {     
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, reverse);
        //You don't need stop() here, but you can change it to play() if you want to resume playback when the mouse is released.
    }
```